# Convert undirected graph to bi- directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given G=(V,E) be a connected, undirected graph.
Is there a way to converted it to directed graph in both directions between two edges.
so if there is A and B as vertex, then A->B and B->A should exist in directed graph.
I want to know algorithm for it, so I can write a code for it. I am not able to think of it.

Comment: If the code uses an adjacency matrix to describe the graph, then you're already done.

Comment: we are not using adjacency matrix, we are just given G. if we were to use adjacency matrix, how would it look like?

Comment: How is G represented? There are several ways to encode graphs, and depending on which one you're using the answer will be different.

Answer (score 0):

A fast way to represent a graph with 10 nodes: representing the adjacency list of a node as a set.

```
set<int> G[10];
```

Then, just do

```
for(int u = 0; u < 10; u++){    //for each node u
    for(int v : G[u]){          //for each node v where exists an edge (u → v)

        if(!G[v].contains(u)) G[v].insert(u);    //add the missing edge (v → u) 

   }
}
```

**Complexity:** O(V + E lg(V))

If you want, you can use `unordered_set` instead of `set` and make the complexity O(V + E).

Comment: so if i replace set by unordered_set, that would be fine to get complexity O(V+E)? so for second for loop, if edge u -> v does not exist, then? since we are given undirected graph

Comment: Yes, the complexity becomes O(V+E). If u->v doesn't exist, once the `for` is looking the edges in `v` and find an edge v->u, it will add an edge u->v.